# How does MacOS developer navigate large code base

Tags: xcode, macos

I am new to MacOS development. I would like to know how developer navigate code in a large code base on MacOS? E.g. webkit?  I have webkit (c++) built in XCode, but the source code navigate is not that great.
I am looking for something like Java source code navigation in eclipse.  e.g. display class hierarchy, e.g. caller of a particular method?

Any one has any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the "Project Symbols" item in the `Groups & Files` sidebar.

If you double-click it, there are more view/filters, like only showing your project's classes:

[Project Symbols http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/6709/symbolbrowserwebkit.png](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/6709/symbolbrowserwebkit.png)

Answer (score 1):

[TextMate](http://macromates.com/) (commercial program) has a project browser, it's better than just using XCode to get an overview. For navigating the many files to see how the big projects are layed out, you need a good file manager, such as [PathFinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Class Browser may help.
Project->Class Browser or Command+Shift+C